# Functions Causing Objects to Disappear

Tags: r, function, variables, object, spatstat

This is a very strange situation that I've come across.  Basically, I'm trying to fit a cumulative distribution function to the G function of my data.  After doing so, I want to plot the the model and the original data, and output this as PDF.  I'll allow the code to explain (simply copy and paste):

```
library(spatstat)

data(swedishpines)

mydata <- swedishpines

mydata.Gest <- Gest(mydata)

Gvalues <- mydata.Gest$rs

count <- (which(Gvalues == 1))[1]

new_r <- seq(1/count, length(Gvalues)/count, by = 1/count)

GvsR_dataframe <- data.frame(G <- Gvalues, R <- new_r)

themodel <- suppressWarnings(nls(G ~ pnorm(R, mean, sd), data = GvsR_dataframe, start = list(mean=0.4, sd=0.2), trace = FALSE))

pdf(file = "ModelPlot.pdf")

plot(mydata.Gest, cbind(rs, theo) ~ new_r, lty = c(1, 2), col = c("black", "red"), xlim = c(0, max(new_r)), ylim = c(0,1), main = paste("Model-fitting for G Function \n Mean = ",as.numeric(coef(themodel)[1]),"\n Standard Deviation = ",as.numeric(coef(themodel)[2]), sep=''), ylab = "G(r)", xlab = "Distance Between Particles (r)", legend = NULL)
lines(new_r, predict(themodel), lty = 2, col = "blue")
legend("bottomright", c("CSR", "Swedish Pines", "Normal Probability \n Density Function"), lty = c(2, 4, 1, 2), col = c("red", "black", "blue"), bg = 'grey', border = 'black')

graphics.off()
```

The above code works perfectly.

Now for the strange part.

When I encapsulate all of the commands after `mydata <- swedishpines` as a function, and cause `mydata` to be an input to this function, it doesn't work any longer.  The following code *should* perform just as the last segment of code did, but it does not.

```
library(spatstat)

data(swedishpines)

mydata <- swedishpines

ModelFit <- function(mydata) {

mydata.Gest <- Gest(mydata)

Gvalues <- mydata.Gest$rs

count <- (which(Gvalues == 1))[1]

new_r <- seq(1/count, length(Gvalues)/count, by = 1/count)

GvsR_dataframe <- data.frame(G <- Gvalues, R <- new_r)

themodel <- suppressWarnings(nls(G ~ pnorm(R, mean, sd), data = GvsR_dataframe, start = list(mean=0.4, sd=0.2), trace = FALSE))

pdf(file = "ModelPlot.pdf")

plot(mydata.Gest, cbind(rs, theo) ~ new_r, lty = c(1, 2), col = c("black", "red"), xlim = c(0, max(new_r)), ylim = c(0,1), main = paste("Model-fitting for G Function \n Mean = ",as.numeric(coef(themodel)[1]),"\n Standard Deviation = ",as.numeric(coef(themodel)[2]), sep=''), ylab = "G(r)", xlab = "Distance Between Particles (r)", legend = NULL)
lines(new_r, predict(themodel), lty = 2, col = "blue")
legend("bottomright", c("CSR", "Swedish Pines", "Normal Probability \n Density Function"), lty = c(2, 4, 1, 2), col = c("red", "black", "blue"), bg = 'grey', border = 'black')

graphics.off()

}

ModelFit(mydata)
```

The following error occurs:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'new_r' not found
```

I'm VERY confused.  I've been working on this for a long time, and just could not come up with a solution to this problem.  The PDF is outputted, but it is corrupt, and will not open.  I have no idea why `new_r` 'disappears', but in doing so, it causes all of the plotting operations to halt.  Obviously `new_r` is local to the function `ModelFit`, but it almost seems as though it's local to certain areas in the function, as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Are you certain the code in your second block is precisely the same code you are executing in R?

Comment: I am sure that it is.  All I've changed in the second block is a function definition (which now contains the majority of the code from the first block), followed by a call to that function.

Comment: Interesting.  I'd appreciate any help, as I'm trying to run a large program in batch mode on a linux server, and this small segment of code has caused me a lot of grief.

Comment: Disregard the above comments- I discovered that it does not throw the error only when I already had run the previous, working code in the same space.

Comment: Justin's answer below, putting in `mydata.Gest$r <- new_r`, works.

Comment: It's a great solution, and probably more elegant than my original code.  However, it still doesn't answer the question of where `new_r` was lost.  If you get the chance, read my comment on Justin's answer - I'd be interested to get to the bottom of this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing a lot of implicit stuff in there... I would suggest writing things more explicitly.

Specifically, `mydata.Gest$r <- new_r` then replace `new_r` with `r` in your plot formula, `plot(..., cbind(rs, theo) ~ r, ...)`.  That works for me.  Not sure why it works outside of a function and not inside, but relying on `plot` to look outside the local scope of `mydata.Gest` for `new_r` is  risky.

Also, use `=` to assign things to columns in a data frame rather than `<-`

From a clean session:

```
data.frame(x<-1:10, y<- 1:10)
ls()
```

versus

```
data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
ls()
```

Comment: Very nice solution, Justin, thank you!

I'm still put off by the fact that we haven't pin-pointed where the error is occurring, however.  I've used the process I posted before, and I've never had any problems with it.  The difference between my previous uses and the one I've posted is that none of the others involve `nls`.  The only possible fault I see occurring is that, after using `new_r` to create `GvsR_dataframe`, perhaps the `new_r` object is deleted after being used by `nls`.  I am very curious, and would like to get to the bottom of this issue.

Comment: I think it has more to do with the way `plot.Gest` is written. Its in that call that you run into problems. you can use `new_r` in other portions of the plot call, but the formula portion doesn't seem to look beyond the local scope of the data argument.

Comment: I've used `plot.Gest` before in a context where the independent variable used was an object outside of the plot function, AND not affiliated with `mydata.Gest`.  That's what makes me think it has something to do with `nls`.

Comment: you can add lines to your function like `print(head(new_r))` to help sort this out.  you can also use `debugonce(ModelFit)` to step through the function inside its scope.